# iOS Analyze - Assuming "self" is non-nill

Tags: ios, objective-c

i´m analyzing my app and runt into the following error. Can someone help me out?

```
- (id)initWithLayer:(id)layer
{
    self = [super initWithLayer:layer];

    if (self)
    {
        [self setDefaults];

        MCNewCustomLayer *other = (MCNewCustomLayer*)layer;
        self.value              = other.value;
        self.textLabel          = other.textLabel;
        self.selectionStatus    = other.selectionStatus;
        self.animationDuration  = other.animationDuration;
        self.mainPath           = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(other.mainPath);
        self.fillColor          = CGColorCreateCopy(other.fillColor);
        self.strokeColor        = CGColorCreateCopy(other.strokeColor);
        self.mainPathImage      = other.mainPathImage;
        self.identifier         = other.identifier;
        self.parentLayeredView  = other.parentLayeredView;
        self.isAllowedToAnimate = other.isAllowedToAnimate;
        self.imageBoundsStyle   = other.imageBoundsStyle;

        self.isPresentationLayer  = YES;

    }

    return self;


}
```

The warning message is like this:

Assuming 'self' is non-nil

Call to function 'CGPathCreateMutableCopy' returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count

Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

Comment: More details can be found in [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation : Ownership Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html).

Comment: I think you want to bridge the objects to ARC.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call `CGPathRelease(other.mainPath);` to release a retain count so that you won't have memory leaks.

Comment: Where exactly do i have to add it?